# Show a square Cursor

Tags: qt, hover, cursor, qwidget

How could I show a square instead of a cursor in QT for eraser in drawing app?

In other words how could I have a square with a side of a specific length instead of a cursor when I am hovering over the `QWidget`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a QPixmap that draws the rectangle creating a QCursor and then set it to the widget you want.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QPixmap pixmap(QSize(64, 64));
    pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);

    QPainter painter(&pixmap);
    QRect r(QPoint(), pixmap.size());
    r.adjust(1, 1, -1, -1);
    painter.drawRect(r);
    painter.end();

    QCursor cursor(pixmap);

    QWidget w;
    QHBoxLayout lay(&w);

    QGraphicsView view1;
    view1.setCursor(cursor);

    QGraphicsView view2;

    lay.addWidget(&view1);
    lay.addWidget(&view2);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Would it be easy to change the square to a circle? Could you please, help me do that?

Comment: @oobarbazanoo `painter.drawRect(r)` --> `painter.drawEllipse(r)`

Comment: Oh! Thank you a lot. You saved my day. (x

Comment: @oobarbazanoo 
Not only use the solution but understand it, but next time you will want a triangle and you will ask for help again, so with the infinite figures, and I am finite, I will never help you forever. :)